# How to visit URL to render page inside Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display chart image to PDF with dompdf. So I'm create page for render chart, after page render it will be send post to save image. It works when I'm visit URL page in browser it save image in storage. My problem is how to call URL to render page without through browser ?

I was tried with file_get_contents method but it required AUTH so chart image not save in storage. This is method generate data for PDF.

```
public function generatedPdf($id_siswa){
    //Provide image chart for pdf
    file_get_contents('http://siswaku/chart/'+$id_siswa); //this is not work to save image in storage

    //Provide data for pdf
    $kompetensi = Kompetensi::join('bidang_kompetensi', function($join){
        $join->on('kompetensi.id_bidang','=','bidang_kompetensi.id')
        ->select('nama_bidang');
    })
    ->where('id_siswa', $id_siswa)
    ->where('active', 1)
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('nama_bidang');

    return ['kompetensi' => $kompetensi];
}
```

My Expect before render PDF, image is available in storage

Comment: Welcome! It would be helpful to supply any code snippets you have attempted to aide giving a more technical answer.  
BTW. Can you redirect to the PDF without loading the PDF file contents?

Comment: yes, this problem is provide image chart for PDF, i don't know how to render page image without through browser. so i can't load image chart from local storage in PDF